# Append new lines to stream, until certain number is reached

Tags: linux, text-processing, command-line, sed, conky

I'm using this command, which searches pacman.log for packages updated today and converts them into a conky string:

```
tail -500 /var/log/pacman.log | grep -e "\[$(date +"%Y-%m-%d") [0-5][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\] \[ALPM\] upgraded" | sed 's/^.*\([0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\).*upgraded \([^ ]*\).*/${color2}\2${goto 250}${color1}\1/' | tail -18
```

With tail -18 the maximum number of lines is 18.

What is the best way to append new lines so that the stream always has 18 lines?

Comment: You’ve ... already limited it to 18 lines. Do you need to pad the output *up* to 18?

Comment: It should always have excactly 18 lines because of padding. Now only the maximum lines is 18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do (with a shell with support for zsh's `{x..y}` form of brace expansion like `zsh`, `bash`, `ksh93` or `yash -o braceexpand`):

```
{
  printf '%.0s\n' {1..18}
  your-command
} | tail -n 18
```

Note that it *prepends* newline as opposed to appending them. To append, you could do:

```
your-command | tail -n 18 | awk '{print};END{while (NR++ < 18) print ""}'
```

Comment: For me it just outputs empty lines
If I do it without awk output is
´${color2}apr${goto 250}${color1}02:51
${color2}apr-util${goto 250}${color1}02:51
${color2}chromium${goto 250}${color1}08:47´

Comment: @Rua4da, d'uh sorry, I forgot the `{print}`, I keep doing it. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

With `bash` you can use c-style loop:

```
other_command | for((i=0;i<18;i++)); do IFS= read -r line; printf '%s\n' "$line";done
```

But where you don't have `bash`, use `awk` Stéphane Chazelas suggests.

Comment: Strictly speaking, that's ksh93 syntax (now also recognised by `zsh` and `bash`). It still needs the `tail -n 18` as otherwise it would get the head instead of tail.